# Play json: parse json value to string without quotes

Tags: scala, play-json

I have a json object lets say

```
{
    "company":"77160"
}
```

And I parse it in Scala with play.api.libs.json like this:

```
cols = Json.parse(line).as[JsObject]
val company = s"${cols("company")}".toString
```

yet the returned string has double quotes (i.e., ""77160"")
What gives? How do I get a normal string ((i.e., "77160")) without reparsing it myself (with replace function for example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call `.as[String]` on `cols("company")`. See https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ScalaJson#Using-JsValue.as/asOpt.

Like so:

```
cols = Json.parse(line).as[JsObject]
val company = cols("company").as[String]
```

In case you're wondering what's happening under the hood, the `as` method is of type `JsValue.as[T](implicit fjs: Reads[T]): T` and it uses implicits to find an implicit converter for `T`. Since we are using `as[String]` here, it will search for an implicit converter that fits that type and since play already defined it in its [library](https://github.com/playframework/play-json/blob/master/play-json/shared/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/json/Reads.scala#L472-L477), it will use that converter.

Comment: Ok, this one works. Does the as keyword use reflection. Because I'm also concerned about speed and this one might be a bit slow

Comment: Use `.validate[T]` rather than `.as[T]`, to have error details